# Is there something like mathjax for chemical structures?

Tags: cms, images, user-generated-content

I am making a website where people can ask and answer questions to bioinformatical matters. I was very delighted with mathjax and its easy use. Is there something like that for chemical structures?

Or is there another way I can easily give users a way to view and write chemical structures/chemical equations on my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that MathJax v2.0 includes a [mhchem](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#mhchem) extension that supports the `\ce` macro for writing chemical equations.  Perhaps that will help?

Answer (score 1):

[Mimox](http://immunet.cn/mimox/) or [biopearl](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-bioinfo3/index.html) might do what you're asking...